# Differentiate between javascript file and libraries (like jquery etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to identify if the javascripts included in the website are libraries ?

I mean, the websites generally load several javascript files using 
     tag... I want to know if the file which is being loaded is library (like jquery) or if it is a normal javascript.

Is there a way to find this?

Thanks in advance, 
Irfan

Comment: There's nothing about a "library" that makes it any different from any other JavaScript code. In what way to you want to "identify" this information.  You say you "want to know" ... what does that mean? Can't you just look at the HTML and see what the `<script>` tags say?

Comment: Well, when I see the page source, I can find out... But My program doest know how to differentiate normal JS and JS libraries... I meant, I want the program to differentiate between JS files and JS Libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any difference between a javascript file and a "library", they are just normal javascript files. You can't differentiate them.

Infact your logical way to identify libraries is from *well known names* and not from a specific parameter.

If you want you can implement a method that looks for well known names, but someone can also rename their javascript files to make them look like libraries for your script.

There is another important note: in rails (for example), all javascript files can be merged into a single one to preserve bandwith usage (they are uglyfied), so maybe you will have name like "v9834kc90l2d0vk34r5lcve.js" which **also** contains a library. I don't think you can identify it easily.

Why are you doing this by the way?

Comment: I am trying to analyze javascripts and find if they are accessing DOM elements and if they are accessing user information from javascript. For doing this I dont want to analyze the libraries... I want to just analyze the javascript which affects the page. Is there a way I can do it ?

Comment: Quite hard as work. I suggest you to use the *well known names* approach. Nothing else can work I think. Even this is just a really ugly approach which definitely won't work a lot of times, there isn't really a way to identify this.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way I can find only the part of the javascript  (from the library)which is being used ?

Comment: I think you can do it, javascript parser understand how to do it and also IDEs (if you don't use eval) understand where a function is. However this is a long code that will take time to be written, I can't put an example.

Comment: can you suggest me some javascript parser? I tried Rhino and Htmlunit... But those give lot of errors when I execute JS from them...

Comment: Sorry, I never used one of them, can't help with this :\

Answer (score 1):

you can parse the file, a jquery file will start with

```
/*! jQuery v?.?.? jquery.com | jquery.org/license */
```

or

```
/*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v?.?.?
 * http://jquery.com/
```

other libraries have similar headers.

but this isnt a 100% solution since the header can be deleted manualy.

Comment: This solution definitely doesn't work. Ext JS 4, a rather famous library, starts with: /* <blankline>

This file is part of Ext JS 4

Answer (score 0):

Javascript libraries *are* normal Javascript files.

If you want to tell which included files are libraries you can inspect them yourself and reach your own conclusion.

If you want to determine which are libraries programmatically, you can't do this. I mean, what constitutes a library? If I have a JS file with two functions in it is it a library?

You probably could write a function to identify some of the popular libraries based on their standard file names, though obviously that wouldn't catch all cases even of those libraries since there's nothing stopping individual programmers from renaming the files when they use them.

Also for the well-known libraries if your program can read the contents of the include file you could look for some string that you know is included in a particular library. Again far from foolproof.

Or you can put some code after the external scripts are included, to test whether certain global variables are defined, e.g., if there's a `jQuery` global then you could reasonably assume that jQuery has been included...

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to write a program which will extract only the used functions from the huge library ?